# Questions about pygsheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I tried three different ways to update values of a google sheets, but none of them works, I went through the pygsheet docs but I still can't find a solution to it.

```
import pandas as pd

import pygsheets as pyg

gc=pyg.authorize(service_account_file=r'C:\Users\mingyu\Downloads\heroic-icon-311506-93b9b87f2fed.json')

sht=gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sX7Rb6Z9E1_JdG-Uf4HdcjxawgC3RLoRt1m7Akn40DQ/edit?hl=zh-TW#gid=0')
wk_list=sht.worksheets()
wks=sht[0]

cell_list=wks.range('A3:A4')
wks.update_values(cell_list,values=[[0,2]])
```

and it goes

```
InvalidArgumentValue: crange
```

then I tried

```
wks.update_values(cell_list=cell_list,values=[[0,2]])
```

it shows

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

after that I tried crange

```
wks.update_values(crange='A3:A4',values=[[0,2]])
```

the error message is

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1sX7Rb6Z9E1_JdG-Uf4HdcjxawgC3RLoRt1m7Akn40DQ/values/%E5%B7%A5%E4%BD%9C%E8%A1%A81%21A1%3AA2?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json returned "Requested writing within range ['工作表1'!A1:A2], but tried writing to column [B]". Details: "Requested writing within range ['工作表1'!A1:A2], but tried writing to column [B]">
```

```
wks.update_values('A3:A4',values=[[0,2]])
```

get me the same thing

I found the docs, it said the 'cell_list: List of a :class:`Cell` objects to update with their values.', then why can't I execute the codes above?

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- From your script, I thought that you might want to put the value of `[[0,2]]` to the range of `A3:A4`.

  - In this case, when you want to put the values of `0` and `2` to `A3:A4`, `[[0,2]]` is required to be `[[0],[2]]`.
  - When you want to put the values of `0` and `2` to `A3:B3`, `A3:A4` is required to be `A3:B3` with `[[0,2]]`.
  - I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
wks.update_values(cell_list,values=[[0,2]])
```

#### To:

If you want to put the values of `0` and `2` to the cells `A3` and `A4`, respectively, please modify as follows.

```
wks.update_values(crange="A3:A4", values=[[0], [2]])
```

or, you can also put the start cell range like below.

```
wks.update_values(crange="A3", values=[[0], [2]])
```

or, you can use `majordim="COLUMNS"`.

```
wks.update_values(crange="A3:A4", values=[[0, 2]], majordim="COLUMNS") # or crange="A3"
```

If you want to put the values of `0` and `2` to the cells `A3` and `B3`, respectively, please modify as follows.

```
wks.update_values(crange="A3:B3", values=[[0, 2]])
```

or, you can also put the start cell range like below.

```
wks.update_values(crange="A3", values=[[0, 2]])
```

#### Reference:

- [update_values(crange=None, values=None, cell_list=None, extend=False, majordim='ROWS', parse=None)](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html?highlight=update_values#pygsheets.Worksheet.update_values)